# I got app built error, duplicate value for resource 'attr/arc_position' with config ''

Tags: java, android, android-layout, sdk

I create new package name `com.taskapp.android`, old package name is `com.servicebooking.app` inside package source and resource file copy and past new package but i got error in Taskapp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml: duplicate value for resource `attr/arc_position` with config ''.

Comment: delete build folder from project main directory. It keeps generated file.

Comment: I deleted build folder and again generate build file it's have same error

Comment: Open terminal and run this command `./gradlew cleanBuildCache`. This will clean up and cached build files.